# SSIS Batch Import CSVs to Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I just got started using SSIS in Visual Studio 2008 and learned how to create a project to point at a folder of CSVs and then import into a table on my SQL Server.  The next step for me is trying to make this even more dynamic, where I can point at a folder of CSVs, with varying structures and create a new table for each CSV file in the folder.

With each CSV having its own structure in terms of the number of columns,  all use double quotes for text qualification, first row headers and are delimited by a comma. I haven't been able to figure out how parameterize dynamically creating a new table with a corresponding name in the Data Flow step.  The Flat File Source is able to generate the SQL to create the table for the first flat file but the next CSV is different and fails. Is this possible?

Comment: Do the csv files change daily/weekly/whenever or is there a fixed set of files that have specific columns with new data in them that gets refreshed?  It seems to me just importing any file that gets put there into a new table would get unwieldy pretty fast.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the columns change over time.  It is historic data and while the general structure has stayed the same (maybe 70% of the columns are always there), over the months new data points/columns have been added and other months things removed, added back in, etc. Because of this volatility in the design of the data, this is why we wanted to create a generalized procedure for these imports.  Hope that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Does the number of files change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, SSIS does not have a component to dynamically detect the structure of a CSV/Text file, parse it accordingly and then prepare it for loading into some table.

Your task does not look like an "ETL tool task" to me. It looks more like a programming task. ETL tools are good only for "common tasks" and not custom tasks. So, I would do it like this in SSIS - create a control table which has the parameters like file location and name, columns like "delimiter", "row header" etc. Then, make a Script task (.net programming !) to set these params to parse your file as per structure and load them in the destination table(s), all with programming inside SSIS. Perhaps you can have another control table to decide which file goes to which DB/table and with which name.

Also, if this is a one time or rare task which involves only 5-10 files, then I suggest that you do it manually instead of making code for it. Programming a file parser
maybe "simple", but its not a trivial task. Search google on how to parse CSV/Text files.

Answer (score -1):

A low-tech solution to this problem is combining all the CSVs into one excel file and then importing that excel using the import/export wizard in SQL Server.

This website has the VBA script required to combine all the CSVs into one excel file: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3230-excel-import-multiple-csv-files.html

Comment: I was looking to batch load a bunch of data files that have *different* structures/target tables in the DB - "where I can point at a folder of CSVs, with varying structures and create a new table for each CSV file in the folder".  Combining multiple CSVs to a single CSV doesn't work if their structures are not the same (which they aren't).